# Click a specific button on another form

Tags: vb.net

Consider i am having two forms, form1 and form2

How can i click,mouse over(any events) a specific button on another form using coding in vb.net?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Are you just trying to execute some code in Form1 from Form2?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that Form1 launches Form2, since there's not a whole lot of information in the description.

When Form1 launches, there are two buttons:  "button1" and "Launch Form 2" (forgot to change text on button1, sorry. :(

[image: form1]

When you click "Launch Form 2", Form2 pops up:

[image: form2]

Clicking the "button1" on Form1, a message box originating from Form1 pops up saying:

[image: form1Message]

Clicking the "button1" on Form2, a message box ALSO originating from Form1 pops up saying:

[image: form2Message]

Here's the code:

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents frm2 As New Form2

    Private Sub Form1Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Form1Button.Click
        RunSomeCode("Called from form 1!")
    End Sub

    Public Sub RunSomeCode(ByVal message As String)
        MessageBox.Show(message)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1LaunchForm2Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Form1LaunchForm2Button.Click
        frm2.Activate()
        frm2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frm2_SimulateForm1ButtonClick() Handles frm2.SimulateForm1ButtonClick
        RunSomeCode("Called from form 2!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2

    Public Event SimulateForm1ButtonClick()

    Private Sub Form2Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Form2Button.Click
        RaiseEvent SimulateForm1ButtonClick()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**How it works**

Form 2 has a public event called "SimulateForm1ButtonClick".  That event can be raised whenever you want, from any code block.  I just decided to raise it when I click the button on the form.

Form 1 has an instance of Form2 **WithEvents**.  It's very important that you use the WithEvents keyword, or that public event in Form2 won't show up. :(

Form 1 has a sub that handles the "SimulateForm1ButtonClick" that is raised when Form2 clicks its button.

Now, here's another important detail:  The code executed when button1 is clicked on Form1 is actually in a private sub called RunSomeCode().  This is important, because it makes the code accessible from any other part of Form1, namely the part that handles Form2's event.

I hope that helps you out a little bit.  I'm not sure exactly what you were asking. :/

Code: http://darin.hoover.fm/code/dl/FormsSandbox.zip

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to fire the event, just use `Form2.Button1.PerformClick()` assuming that the button on form 2 is called 'button1'.

Comment: I would prefer to put the code from the click-method in a separate method which is public. So you can call this method in both forms.

Comment: `Public Sub Button1_Click`
`Form2.Button1.PerformClick()`
`End Sub`